# height of div doesn't go along

Tags: css, html

I have a container `div`, within that `div` are other `div`'s.  In there I use jQuery `.show()` to show stuff.

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    font-size: 15;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}
```

The content `div` grows longer than the container `div`, so the white background stops when I scroll down, leaving me with no white background there.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: So where's your HTML code?  How about a link or a demo?

Comment: Try using `min-height: 100%` instead. It is hard to know what the actual problem is without a demo. Try to reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and then link it in your question.

Comment: It's actually impossible to know how to help when the HTML is missing.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/K6PAn/8/

I think this will be your answer, Adding padding to the top and bottom will always make the white shown.

Hope this helps, If it's not the correct answer, sorry! D:

Comment: You can not possibly know the answer to this question when the OP has failed to provide any of his actual HTML code.

Comment: He said one within the other, so i put the content in the container as an assumption

Answer (score -1):

Add an extra div at the end of the content with clear:both e.g.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Dave

Comment: It never harms to add the clear:both.
Unless you absolutely require the height in the container remove that altogether and the div height will automatically be set to the height of the content (just tested).
Dave

Comment: **1.**  It does not answer the question, and **2.**  `clear` is **only** used for [clearing floats and nothing else](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control).  Adding superfluous code because of ignorance only perpetuates poor coding habits.